# Trying to write quick sort algorithm in c++ and getting error

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector, qsort

So I am trying to write quicksort algorithm in c++ with vectors.

```
template <typename T>
T qsort(vector<T> arr) 
{
    int mid_idx = round(arr.size() / 2);
    int root_el = arr[mid_idx];
    
    vector<T> smaller;
    vector<T> bigger;
    vector<T> equals;
    for (T i: arr)
    {
        if (arr[i] > root_el)
            bigger.push_back(arr[i]);
        else if (arr[i] < root_el)
            smaller.push_back(arr[i]);
        else
            equals.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
    return (qsort(smaller) + equals + qsort(bigger));
}
```

And I am getting this error:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'vector<int>') [Semantic Issue]
```

So can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Well, what do you expect the result of `qsort(smaller) + equals + qsort(bigger)` to be? There is indeed no `operator+` for that operation

Comment: Functions are often easier to debug when their purpose is documented, even when you think it is pointless. For example, could you write out the interface specs for this function? What is to be supplied as the input parameter, and what is to be returned? Does this match what you have declared?

Comment: Seemingly, you are taking the template parameter to be "integer": the fifth line, int root_el = arr[mid_idx]; left is integer, but the right is of type T. And also inside the for loop, the element of type T is logically compared to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with this C++ code.

The `qsort` template function clearly intends to return a vector, from the `return` instruction at the end. But it is declared as returning a single object of type T.

Also, the vector argument is passed by *value*, which is expensive for large vectors (duplication). I suggest to pass it by reference instead.

So we could change the top declaration to this:

```
template <typename T>
vector<T>  qsort(vector<T>& arr) 
{
```

**A more fundamental problem:** from the code, it seems that every call to `qsort` causes, recursively and unconditionally, two more calls to `qsort`. If the function is written that way, the program cannot terminate. Or rather, the operating system will kill it when it has exhausted stack space and thus makes some illegal memory access.

Every recursive algorithm needs some terminating condition. In our case, there is nothing to do if the size of the array is less than 2, as it is obviously already sorted.

So the beginning of the `qsort` function could be written this way:

```
#include  <vector>
#include  <cmath>
#include  <iostream>

using  std::vector;

template <typename T>
vector<T>  qsort(vector<T>& arr) 
{
    if (arr.size() < 2)
        return arr;  // so small it is already sorted !
```

Also, in the for loop, variable `i` is used as an integer index, but is declared as an object of type T. The loop could be written like this instead:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > root_el)
            bigger.push_back(arr[i]);
        else if (arr[i] < root_el)
            smaller.push_back(arr[i]);
        else
            equals.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
```

Now, we come to the final `return` instruction:

```
    return (qsort(smaller) + equals + qsort(bigger));
```

The line of code above obviously assumes that for vectors, the “+” operator means vector concatenation. But actually this is left undefined in the C++ standard. So there is no definition for vector “+” in scope, even after including the `<vector>` header file.

Furthermore, if the question of standardizing “+” for vectors ever came before the international C++ standardization committee, there would be tremendous pressure, notably from the computational physics community, in favor of defining it in the *traditional way* as found in common math and physics textbooks.

That is, the value of `[10,20,30] + [2,4,6]` would have to be `[12,24,36]` and **not** `[10,20,30,2,4,6]` as your code seems to imply.

So we have to do this vector concatenation *manually*, like this for example, using the [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) STL method:

```
    auto  lts = qsort(smaller);
    auto  gts = qsort(bigger);

    // concatenate sorted vectors:
    lts.insert(lts.end(),  equals.begin(),  equals.end());
    lts.insert(lts.end(),  gts.begin(),     gts.end());

    return lts;
```

Overall, the following version of the code works as expected:

```
template <typename T>
vector<T>  qsort(vector<T>& arr) 
{
    if (arr.size() < 2)
        return arr;  // so small it is already sorted !

    int  mid_idx  =  arr.size() / 2;
    T    root_el  =  arr[mid_idx];

    vector<T>  smaller;
    vector<T>  bigger;
    vector<T>  equals;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > root_el)
            bigger.push_back(arr[i]);
        else if (arr[i] < root_el)
            smaller.push_back(arr[i]);
        else
            equals.push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    auto  lts = qsort(smaller);
    auto  gts = qsort(bigger);

    // concatenate sorted vectors:
    lts.insert(lts.end(),  equals.begin(),  equals.end());
    lts.insert(lts.end(),  gts.begin(),     gts.end());

    return lts;
}
```

**Testing code:**

```
int main()
{

    vector<int>  v1 { 609,396,620,173, 742,996,880,125,
                      478,745,206,798, 998,124,960,175  };

    vector<int>  v2 = qsort(v1);

    for (auto m : v2) {
        std::cout << m << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Program output:**

```
$ ./q64784877.x
124 125 173 175 206 396 478 609 620 742 745 798 880 960 996 998 
$
```

### Notes on efficiency:

Your code creates a number of temporary vectors, and thus dynamically allocates a significant amount of memory. If you look at the [traditional versions of Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), the code does not allocate any extra memory. It does all its work within the initial array, but that makes the algorithm slightly more complex.

Also, the code aboves uses recursion *to the very bottom end*, stopping only when the subvectors are down to a size of 1. In practice, it is probably more efficient to switch to a non-recursive, simpler algorithm such as [Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) when the subarray size is down to 10 or 15. To be tested on your platform for the exact optimal threshold value.